# How can I refer secrets from custom resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, fabric8, kubernetes-secrets

How can I refer secret value from custom resource ?
I am trying some thing like below but its not working

```
configuration:
  baseUrl: "some url"
  username: "jack"
  password:
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        key: identityServiceInstanceURL
        name: oauthpassword
```

password is considered as map instead string replacement , it gives below error

```
error: error validating "intg/helm/templates/CRDS.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Test.spec.configuration.password): invalid type for Test.spec.configuration.password: got "map", expected "string"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Comment: It seems your CRD does not support referencing a secret key in the `password` field.

Comment: More specifically, your operator code and the CustomResourceDefinition would need to support this.  The `valueFrom: {secretKeyRef:}` syntax you show is normally very specific to the `env:` field in a Pod spec and isn't understood anywhere else.  Do you have, perhaps, an excerpt of the Kubebuilder Go code for your operator that you could include in your question?